# Why does useCallback with no array args not cause the useState update function to fire?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Here's a simple increment counter:

```
function App() {
  const [value, updateValue] = useState(42);
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    updateValue(value + 1);
  }, []);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      value: {value}
      <button onClick={handleClick}> click me</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[(Code Sandbox)](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-nash-ebt54)

Now, as this is, this code doesn't work properly, only the first increment will happen.

If we change that `useCallback` and put `value` in the array:

```
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    updateValue(value + 1);
  }, [value]);
```

Or, if instead of updating the value to `value + 1`, we update it to `Math.random()`;

```
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    updateValue(Math.random());
  }, []);
```

Both of these scenarios will cause the value to update each click.

What's going on here, and what principle of hooks explains this?

Or more to the point - the reason I'm using `useCallback` in the first place is to avoid creating an inline-function for the onClick event.

ie.

```
 <button onClick={() => updateValue(value +1)}> click me</button>
```

as I understand that has bad performance implications (a new function is created each render, whether or not a diff occurs).

Is using `useCallback` the right way to handle these click events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your first example is that the closure will 'close' on the old state value 42 and will never change.

One way to fix this is to use the functional form of the state setter so that you always have a fresh state value, like this :

```
  const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
    updateValue((value) => value + 1);
  }, []);
```

Another way is like you did, declare the deps in the second param of useCallback

Comment: Ah, yup, the closure is the key thing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`useCallBack` returns the memoized version on your `handleClick` method. Thus if you don't specify any dependency `[]`, it will always return the same method. Since it depends on `value` so when you must pass `value` as dependency then it will return new memozied version with new value on every click so your value will update.

Answer (score 0):

In the `react-hooks` document, they describe this case in FAQs section. You should read carefully to understand how the hooks work.

[What can I do if my effect dependencies change too often?](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#what-can-i-do-if-my-effect-dependencies-change-too-often)